# Is it possible to run Visual Studio Code commands from Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, markdown, palette

Is it possible to run Visual Studio Code commands from Markdown? I noticed that, for example `[cpptools](vscode:extension/ms-vscode.cpptools)` shows the extension's page. I wondered if executing a command from the command palette would also work, and if it is something of an URI.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "...from markdown"?

Comment: Are you trying to make a link that, when clicked, will run a command? I'm 99% sure that isn't possible.

Comment: Hey there, have you found a solution? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link processing using protocol `vscode` for example `[cpptools](vscode:extension/ms-vscode.cpptools)` is performed only by *Visual Studio Code*. For now, it handles links if they point to extensions, but does not support link to commands. But the *Visual Studio Code* development team can add this if they see fit for the developers.

But, in my opinion, this functionality is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It proved difficult to track down the documentation but in fact this *is* possible, see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140733

Say your command is referenced as `pkg.command`, then this URL in Markdown can be clicked to execute it:

```
[Run It](command:pkg.command)
```

This works out of the box in modern VSCode.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I put the command line in configuration property markdown and it works, i.e.         [Run It](command:workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility)  Note: if its your own command make sure extension is activated - otherwise it does not work, the command id - is exactly as declared in package.json